# check Game Object has listener in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, listener

I have a game object in unity  .I need to remove listener from that.But  in use Remove listener command  if game object hasn't listener ,I get Null Reference Exception in unity.

is way to know game object has listener ??

Comment: You need to post post the code that you are using to add the listeners and the code you are using to remove it. We can't help if we can't see what the code looks like. You may want to add the language tag too.

Comment: The problem was solved Thank you for your attention

Comment: Ok. Not sure how this question will help anyone in the future. I think it's better if deleted.